# div's height is not updating after jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Update:** Here is a jdfiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/h9m3t8op/

I'm trying to sort elements by the int value of the `data-cardnumber` attribute. This works fine, but then I try to append the cards in order across a series of 3 columns.
The 3 columns are made with CSS' grid-template-area.

Except, the height isn't updating after the 4th card and then the rest of the cards are being appended to only the first column because that is what I have told it to happen if all the heights are the same.

It appears there is a race condition or height is taking too long to update before the next iteration of the for loop. I've tried jQuery's `.each()` and a normal for loop.

I've asked around and searched online and nothing has worked, but let me list what I found:

- Jquery is caching the variable selector, which I am using for efficiency instead of calling it each time, but changing them to `$('#col1')` instead of `$(col1)`
- Put the appending in a `setTimeout(function(){}, 0);` but that delays too many of the appends and only one of the later ones if any is actually appended
- Remove css animation delays and css animations, this does nothing
- Overflow:hidden on the column to allow for proper calculation of the height, but that does nothing.

For some reason the computed Height is different than the last `.height()` call, which I am logging.

I've tried to make the console output helpful, this is how it reads:

- l (number of cards total)
- ccc (number of cards left in `.cards`, where they are stored before
  put into columns
- The standalone number is which card we are on, starting at 1
- c1 or c2 or c2 h before is the height before appending
- card count on the same line as c1 or c2 or c3 h before is how many cards are in that column
- c1 or c2 or c3 h after is the `.height()` after appending.

I've tried to do as much logging as possible to help. As you can see, the 4th card should go into `#col1`, but the height doesn't update (it stays at 464) or the 5th card does as well and so on and so forth.